# Importing dmp in Oracle

Tags: oracle, import

I am using script to import data from dmp file.  The script is

`imp sys/password file=<file location> full=yes`

but it does not work. It asked for file buffer size and either we put file buffer size or it will be terminated.

Please tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your tags because users filter by them when looking for questions to answer. Feel free to add additional ones.

Comment: Can you add the full run detail. Like how you import, run, and what the response. That'll help to understand the problem and solve it.

Comment: Ofcourse mention source, target DB version, and OS detail.